# Does Android layouts work like HTML/CSS layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, fluid-layout

I have created a button in Photoshop and I have split them into 3 images. Now I want to put those images into android button. I know how to create layouts in android but the point I am missing is how can I make them fluid?

So there is a button for which I have 3 images.

[image: left side] [image: middle one] [image: right side]

I now want to ask how can I use these images for a `<Button>` tag so it expands repeating the middle one. Do I need to create style here and then put `background="@drawable/three_button_style"` or there is something I really need to know?

Is the same going to be true for ListView? I got a list view and images for **top, middle and bottom** so can I create a ListView of 3 images repeating the **middle** one?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scaling items Android usually uses 9-patch, which behaves something like your example but also vertically. Here's a link to the 9-patch tool that can be used to draw these:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html